# questions related to "3D Rotations, Axis-Angle, and Shortest Paths"

Tags: rotations, geodesic

My question is related to [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2726721/3d-rotations-axis-angle-and-shortest-paths): Given two orientation $A,B\in SO(3)$,  and let $P,Q \in S^{3}$ (the 3-sphere in 4-space) such that $f(P) = A$ and $f(Q) = B$. I want to find the "shortest distance" between the given two orientations. My questions are:

1) Does the axis-angle representation give the "shortest distance" between two orientations? I'm not sure if I fully understand Dr. Hughes' answer ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2726739)), it seem to be that he only considers the case when $P$ and $Q$ are close, what if they are not close?

2) Since $P,Q \in S^3$, is the "shortest distance" the same as the distance between $P$ and $Q$ on $S^{3}$ (calculated via integration on manifold)?

3) If my reasoning is correct, is there anyway I can find the close form expression or the interpolation of the geodesic between $P$ and $Q$?

Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Quaternions are often preferred for interpolating between rotations.

Comment: @amd, thank you for that info. I think my problem is how to find this geodesic between $P$ and $Q$ either as analytical expression or discrete data points.

Comment: Any help please :(